# Share internet with only one computer in LAN in windows7

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, windows-firewall

How can I share internet connection of a computer in LAN with another one. All other computers in the LAN should not be able to access internet. All are running on windows 7. Is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible but you don't give enough details to get a proper answer.  How are those devices connected?  Do you have a DHCP server or are they using static IPs?

Comment: Using a DHCP server.

Comment: Do you have a router and if so what model is it?

Comment: Yes, a dlink router. model number:  DES 1008A

Answer (score 0):

First note that the D-Link DES 1008A is not a router but a switch.

The simplest way to do this would be to set up a proxy server, that you would place between the modem (connecting to the Internet) and the switch, to filter by MAC address.

Since you already have a server providing a DHCP service, that would be the best candidate to setup as the proxy server.  I suppose it's probably already the case but you'd need to make sure the default gateway points back to the proxy server.